# Help me set URL using .htaccess in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I use CodeIgniter and I want to set URL by htaccess. I have tried many ways but have not succeeded yet.

My folder structure :

```
--application
----corntrollers
-------public
----------home.php
----------log
-------------- login.php
-------admin
----views
-------public
----------home.tpl
----------log
-------------- login.tpl
--system
--mysite
```

I want to set URL to rewrite :

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/log/login
=>
http://localhost/mysite/log-in
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Enable url rewriting module of Apache2:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Change /config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

As well

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

The correct way of .htaccess is:

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

php_flag short_open_tag on

<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset ETag
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
   Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Restar Apache2 Service:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure url rewriting is enabled and then create .htaccess file with code below.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in `/config/config.php`

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Index File
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
    | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
    | variable so that it is blank.
    |
    */
    $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change

```
$config['index_page']
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Next in

> /config/routes.php

```
$route['log-in'] = "log/log-in";
```